# Alphabetical scroll bar not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexing

I'm trying to make an alphabetical scroll bar like the scroll bar in Contacts and in Apple Music. However, when I call `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` method, the alphabetical scroll bar does not show up. How do I fix this? I referenced this [older tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) and [newer tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/ios/indexed-table-views-in-swift/).

**Code**

```
class SongsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private var sectionTitles = ["A", "B", "C"]

    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {
        return sectionTitles as [AnyObject]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return sectionTitles.index(of: title)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tutorials are for earlier versions of Swift.  The current function signatures are:

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return sectionTitles
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionTitles.index(of: title)!
}
```